# CNN not learning correctly

Tags: deep-learning, regression, pytorch, conv-neural-network, multiclass-classification

I've a small dataset of 500 plant images and I have to predict a number for a single image in range [1, 10]. There is a order relation between the numbers (10 > 9 > ... > 1). This problem is similar to age estimation based on a single photo.

I tried regression using Resnet18, Resnet34 and VGG16. None of them gave a very good result.

The interesting point is that when I plotted the heatmap for a few images it showed that the model was picking the wrong spots to predict the answer. It's like, if I was suppose to predict age based on facial photo, the cnn gave more value to the background than to the actual face.

I tried other approachs as well, like classification and learning to rank, but it happens the same thing when I do heatmap. In these approachs, the best accuracy I get is 30% using classification and 35% using learning to rank.

The regression and classification approachs I used Fastai implementation with pretrained. The learning to rank approach I used this : https://github.com/Raschka-research-group/coral-cnn. I changed a little bit to be able to use a pretrained model as well.

Another important point is that the dataset is unbalanced. 80% of the dataset corresponds to classes 6 to 10.

Does anyone has any tips to improve it or another approach I could try?

EDIT:
My data augmentation looks like this:

```
transforms.Compose([
                  transforms.Resize(256), transforms.CenterCrop(224),
                  transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(p=0.5),
                  transforms.ColorJitter(brightness=0.15), 
                  transforms.ToTensor(),
                  transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.299, 0.224, 0.225])
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try augmenting your dataset to obtain more data (e.g. random cropping, rotating, etc), and make sure you normalise your data. For the class imbalance problem, you can try using PyTorch's `WeightedRandomSampler`:

```
#Let there be 9 samples in class 0 and 1 sample in class 1 respectively
class_counts = [9.0, 1.0]
num_samples = sum(class_counts)
labels = [0, 0,..., 0, 1] #corresponding labels of samples

class_weights = [num_samples/class_counts[i] for i in range(len(class_counts))]
weights = [class_weights[labels[i]] for i in range(int(num_samples))]
sampler = WeightedRandomSampler(torch.DoubleTensor(weights), int(num_samples))
```

You should be able to apply this to your case with 10 classes easily, hope this solves your problem!

Comment: Thanks for answering. I've tried your approach but I didn't got better results. Could you check if my data augmentation is correct?